# Displaying list when a button is pressed. error "nothing was returned from render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, admin

I am new to react. I have a list that I have included in my code, when the admin of the page connects they will see an "admin view." I want there to be a button available to the admin that when pressed will result in the list been displayed on screen.

I have tested it without trying to add in the button and the function GetAdminList and it works, the issue has arrived when I have tried to add this to the admin view with a button.

```
const GetAdminList = () =>

{initialAdmins.map(admin => {
        return (
        <div>Admin: {admin.name} {admin.address} {admin.id}</div>);
})
```

and when it is been called with code on admin view when the user presses a button

```
const AdminComponent = () => {
<div>Admin View 
</div>
return (
<div><button onClick = {GetAdminList} > View Admins </button></div>
);
```

}

The code is compiling but when running, comes into the error above, I'm wondering what has went wrong when I have tried to add the button which will when clicked display the list? As stated before it was working without the button when user pressed an (I am admin) button and was verified as admin.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, so you are saying the return should come before the .map? I have tried adding this in and it seems to throw error.

Answer (score 0):

When you click your button function  `GetAdminList` is executed and returns JSX but thats all. The returned JSX isn't rendered anywhere. The better way to do it will be using `useState` hook. By clicking on button you execute `GetAdminList` that changes `isAdminList` from default false to true. Having that state you can conditionally render div with admin list.

```
const AdminComponent = () => {
  const initalAdmins = [{ name: "Admin Name", address: "Adress", id: "01" }];
  const [isAdminList, setIsAdminList] = useState(false);

  const getAdminList = () => {
    setIsAdminList(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Admin View</div>;
      <button onClick={getAdminList}> View Admins </button>
      {isAdminList &&
        initalAdmins.map((admin) => {
          return (
            <div>
              Admin: {admin.name} {admin.address} {admin.id}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
```